# "has:attachment" filter for Yahoo mail IMAP client

Tags: php, gmail, imap, roundcube, yahoo-mail

I am using IMAP client and want to add filter which allows email filtering by attachment, similar to thunderbird. I am able to achieve this for Gmail using **"X-GM-RAW has:attachment"** but didn't got any success for Yahoo mail. What can be the right solution for Yahoo mail ?

Note : Using Roundcube email client for this purpose.

Comment: You can't, there is no standard IMAP search language for this.  You would have to fetch the BODYSTRUCTURE for all messages, cache that, and search that for attachments.

Comment: I tried for gmail it works. Is it problem with Yahoo only ?

Comment: X-GM-RAW is a Gmail extension.  That's what the 'X-GM' means.  It is not standard IMAP.